# how to increase column length without making dependent types invalid in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, types, alter

I need to increase a column length in oracle table. But there is type defined on same table inside a package specification. This package is being used in more than 1000 packages.

So when I alter column, all packages become invalid.

Is there a way, so I can increase column length without making dependent type invalid.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check [online table redefinition](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables007.htm#ADMIN01514) in which case only affected column's dependent objects will become invalid. For example if the column you are altering is not dependant on the type in the same table declared in packages then those packages will remain valid.Even for normal alter command this condition applies but online redefinition allows using a interim table to support dml operations during the alterations

Anyway since it is a production system I suggest testing this feature in UAT and then work it out in production

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do anything; Oracle will recompile (or, at least try to do so) those packages and make them `VALID` (unless something else prevents that).

Here's a simple demonstration.

Test case first:

```
SQL> create table test (name varchar2(5));

Table created.

SQL> insert into test
  2    select 'Littl'  from dual union all
  3    select 'Foot'   from dual;

2 rows created.

SQL> create or replace package pkg_test as
  2    function f_test return test.name%type;
  3  end;
  4  /

Package created.

SQL> create or replace package body pkg_test as
  2    function f_test return test.name%type is
  3      retval test.name%type;
  4    begin
  5      select max(name) into retval from test;
  6      return retval;
  7    end;
  8  end;
  9  /

Package body created.

SQL>
```

Let's check package's status and see function's result:

```
SQL> select object_name, status From user_objects where object_name = 'PKG_TEST';

OBJECT_NAM STATUS
---------- -------
PKG_TEST   VALID
PKG_TEST   VALID

SQL> select pkg_test.f_test from dual;

F_TEST
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Littl

SQL>
```

Everything is OK.

Now, enlarge the column and see what happens:

```
SQL> alter table test modify name varchar2(10);

Table altered.

SQL> select object_name, status From user_objects where object_name = 'PKG_TEST';

OBJECT_NAM STATUS
---------- -------
PKG_TEST   INVALID
PKG_TEST   INVALID

SQL> select pkg_test.f_test from dual;

F_TEST
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Littl

SQL> select object_name, status From user_objects where object_name = 'PKG_TEST';

OBJECT_NAM STATUS
---------- -------
PKG_TEST   VALID
PKG_TEST   VALID

SQL>
```

See? It just *works*. Package was initially `INVALID`, was recompiled *in the background* and became `VALID`.

---

So, no worries. I'd just say *congratulations* you decided to declare *everything* so that it inherits column's datatype. If you hardcoded it, then you'd have a BIG problem in manually modifying all those variables, whatnot, to make everything work.

Comment: thanks for detailed answer... I still have issues with invalid objects even it is for some time only... as this is for production and very critical one

Comment: "Some time" lasts until someone calls that invalid object. Then it is recompiled and becomes valid. I'd just add that I wouldn't recommend you to "force" anything of that during work hours as you won't be able to recompile any object that is being held by user(s).